Prioritization of features in model using $\beta$ coefficients
I was wondering - if you have a model which provides you with the $\beta$ estimates for each variable you include, but no p-value, how could one prioritise the ones with a stronger effect on the outcome?
Note that I do not wish to centre and scale all the variables, I have data of different natures that have been normalized accordingly.
For the continuous variables, I was thinking about considering the coefficient $\tilde{\beta}=\beta_X \cdot range(X)$ or $\tilde{\beta}=\beta_X \cdot sd(X)$, to remove the high dependence between the range of the variables and the $\beta$ estimates.
For the categorical variables, I thought about considering the $\beta$ themselves, as they do not depend on the range of the variable.
Would this approach be correct? If so, how could one objectively compare the effect of continuous variables vs categorical ones?
Thank you!
My idea was to perform feature selection, and they provide with a list of the top selected features, according to importance in the model.

As suggested in the link, centering and scaling your features will make comparable your coefficients. So high values correspond to high importance. LASSO or any penalized models will shrink coefficients towards zeros providing some kind of automatic feature selection method. Features with small or zero coefficients can be removed from your analysis.

But I do not want to centre and scale all the features... I have data of different nature

If you want to choose between variables, you have to be able to compare them. If you just say they are different, then you will have to accept that they cannot be compared. So it is either or: either you find some way to make the variables comparable (which will always be at least somewhat arbitrary) and be able to select variables or you don't want to make that arbitrary choice, but than you cannot select.

The method you propose in your question is a way of standardizing the variables. It's just not the usual one. Also, even if you had p values (and I'm not sure why you don't) I would not use p values for this.
